# jQuery variable visibility inside closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On this code:

```
$.each(divList, function(){ 
    var dropdown = '';
    $.get("ajax.php",{'some':'params', 'other':'params'},function(msg){
        dropdown = msg;
        console.log( dropdown );
    });
    console.log( dropdown );
    $(dropdown).appendTo($(this));
});
```

...the first log shows dropdown variable holds the correct text returned from the ajax, the second one is empty (and the appendTo does nothing).

Is there a way to make this works? Is there some dependency with the browser used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.get()` is *asynchronous*: it returns very quickly, performs its work in the background and signals completion by invoking the callback function you supply.

Since your second call to `console.log()` and your call to `appendTo()` are outside the callback, they will run too soon, before `$.get()` completes and `dropdown` is set.

The usual pattern is to put the call to `appendTo()` inside the callback function:

```
$.each(divList, function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {
            // your parameters...
        },
        context: this,
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            $(msg).appendTo(this);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** If you want to access the original `this` reference from your callback function, you can pass it in the `context` option to [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), as the code above does.

Comment: Do'h. 
Any way to access $(this) (the element in the divList) inside the $.get() method ? Is it possible to save it in a variable or such ?

Comment: Yes, just tried. Just save it with var whatever = $(this) and use it inside the closure. 

Thank you.

Comment: You're sending `context:` to the server. That doesn't help the callback context.

Comment: @amnotiam, very true, `$.ajax()` has to be called to achieve this. Answer updated accordingly, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: It seems that setting the context is the correct way to do this. It also makes the multiple $.get() to work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Assing `this` to a variable at the top of the function so its accessible by the asynchronous ajax call :

```
$.each(divList, function(){ 
    var me = this;
    $.get("ajax.php",{'some':'params', 'other':'params'},function(msg){
        var dropdown = msg;
        console.log( dropdown );
        $(dropdown).appendTo($(me));
    });
})
```

Comment: Seems this does not work

Having multiple $.get in the same context makes only the last appendTo to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assign `this` in the outher scope of `$get` to a new variable, which you can access in your success-handler